# Subset of a countable set is countable

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the full details of a proof on countability. The exact statement is:

> If $A \subset B$ where $B$ is countable, then $A$ is countable.

"Countable" here means finite or countably infinite, but the case where $A$ (or $B$, and hence $A$) are finite are rather vacuous, so let's only consider the case where $A$ and $B$ are infinite. The first line of the proof states:

"It suffices to consider the case where $B = \mathbb{N}$ and $A \subset \mathbb{N}$."

I am trying to understand why this is the case. Here is my best attempt. If $B$ is countable, there is a bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \to B$ and hence another bijection $f^{-1}: B \to \mathbb{N}$. So $f^{-1} (B)$ is countable (in fact, it's the entirety of $\mathbb{N}$), but $A \subset B$, so $f^{-1} (B) \subset f^{-1} (A) = \mathbb{N}$. If we prove that $f^{-1} (B)$ is countable, we have the opposite inclusion and a bijection $g: f^{-1} (B) \to \mathbb{N}$. Then we can "apply" $f$ to compose bijections, getting a bijection from $B$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

The last step is very shaky and I don't think it works. Any idea?

Comment: We have an inclusion $A\hookrightarrow B$, so composing with the bijection $B\to\mathbb N$ yields an injection $$A\hookrightarrow B\to\mathbb N.$$ So we can view $A$ as a subset of $\mathbb N$ in this way.

Comment: This makes sense; but if, say, $f$ is the inclusion and $g$ the bijection $B \to \mathbb{N}$, then $g \circ f$ embeds $A$ in $\mathbb{N}$. How does proving that $(g \circ f)(A)$ is countable show that $f$ is countable?

Comment: $g\circ f$ is a bijection onto it's image, so $|A|=|(g\circ f)(A)|$.

Comment: This makes much more sense. More generally, are we allowed to say that a function is a bijection onto its image if and only if it is injective? (It's surely surjective, by definition.)

Comment: "*but $A \subset B$, so $f^{-1} (B) \subset f^{-1} (A)$*" The containment here is backwards, it should be $f^{-1}(B) \supset f^{-1}(A)$.

Comment: Yes that's exactly right. Note that *any* function is surjective onto it's image, so this gives a bijection onto the image if and only if the function is injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composition of two injective maps is injective.  Compose the inclusion of the subset with the injection into the naturals, to get an injection of the subset into the naturals.

(This question was asked a day or two ago, and is a dupe. Although there the OP insisted on a proof by induction, rather ridiculously.)

Comment: I didn't see that question. Do you have a link to it?

Comment: Sure.  Hold on.  It's on my profile page because I answered it.

Comment: Here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3980318/403337